# What is a good registrar for .me domains?

Tags: domain-registrar

I am currently using 1and1.com for my domains.  I love them: cheap, reliable and, most importantly, clean and intuitive interface.  (Basically the opposite of what I see when I have to login to GoDaddy for a client.)

I want to register a .me domain.  1and1.com does not support this TLD.  Anyone have a good recommendation?  I see this list here, but am unsure which would be good.

http://domain.me/registerame/registrarlist.php

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hosted with TierraNet many years ago.  They were a great company then, and were very responsive to my requests for help.  I haven't used any of their services in a few years, however, so I am not sure if anything has changed.  I currently host with Media Temple, but they don't register .me.

GoDaddy and Network Solutions are two other big names that a lot of my clients use and have success with - they are both on the domain.me list of registrars.  Personally, I can't stand trying to navigate the GoDaddy website - but to each their own.

Comment: Thank you.  I really dislike GoDaddy too, and this is why I was looking for something else.  I'm going to use TierraNet.